# Show file path in firefox/chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I am using javascript/HTML in my code and I want to  get the entire path (something like this:"C:\Users...\abc.jpg) for  the image file I select without using ActiveX objects.But when I use input type file and select any image file it just shows the image name with extension(example abc.jpg) and not the entire path.Please suggest a solution for the same.

Comment: You cant able to get the absolute path,Since it is a security feature in all modern browsers.

Comment: Since this is impossible due to safety issues, most browsers give you a fake path similar to "fakepath\file_name".